# Plotting a second plotspace

Tags: objective-c, core-plot

I have two plot spaces

```
//First Plot Space
self.plotSpace1 =(CPTXYPlotSpace *) self.hostingView.hostedGraph.defaultPlotSpace;

[self.plotSpace1 setYRange: [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(100)]];

[self.plotSpace1 setXRange: [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(([startNumber floatValue]/1000000) ) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat( ([endLength floatValue]/1000000))]];

//Second Plot Space
self.plotSpace2 =(CPTXYPlotSpace *) [self.hostingView.hostedGraph newPlotSpace];
[self.plotSpace2 setGraph:self.hostingView.hostedGraph];
[self.plotSpace2 setYRange: [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(1)]];
[self.plotSpace2 setXRange: [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat( ([startNumber floatValue]/1000000) ) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat( ([endLength floatValue]/1000000) )]];
[self.plotSpace2 setIdentifier:@"PLOT2"];

[self.plotSpace2 setAllowsUserInteraction:YES];

[self.hostingView.hostedGraph addPlotSpace:self.plotSpace2];
```

When I add a plot to the second plot space like so

```
CPTScatterPlot* plot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
plot.title = plotTitle;
plot.dataSource = self;
[plot setPlotSpace:self.plotSpace2];
[self.hostingView.hostedGraph addPlot:plot toPlotSpace:self.plotSpace2];
```

I add a second y axis like so - the second y axis is displayed

```
CPTXYAxis *rightY = [(CPTXYAxis *)[CPTXYAxis alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
rightY.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithUpperOffset:0.0];
rightY.coordinate = CPTCoordinateY;
rightY.plotSpace = self.plotSpace2;


//Labeling and intervals
rightY.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyFixedInterval;
rightY.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(0.1f);
rightY.minorTicksPerInterval = 5;

rightY.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromDouble(self.plotSpace2.xRange.locationDouble + self.plotSpace2.xRange.lengthDouble);
rightY.title = nil;


//Format and position
rightY.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
rightY.titleOffset = 20.0f;
rightY.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
rightY.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
rightY.labelOffset = 2.0f;
rightY.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
rightY.majorTickLength = 4.0f;
rightY.minorTickLength = 2.0f;
rightY.tickDirection = CPTSignPositive;

axisSet.axes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:x, y, rightY, nil];
```

The line is not plotted.  However, if I add it to plotSpace1 (the default plot space) it is plotted.

I have been stuck on this for a while now.  I have searched and searched like crazy for an answer.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first plot space has a `yRange` from 0 to 100 while the second `yRange` extends between 0 and 1. The plot data is probably outside the visible plot range.

You should only add the plot to the graph once:

```
CPTScatterPlot* plot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
plot.title = plotTitle;
plot.dataSource = self;
[self.hostingView.hostedGraph addPlot:plot toPlotSpace:self.plotSpace2];
```

Comment: Hey Eric, Thank you for the reply. I'm new to core plot and I'm probably not fully understanding what I'm doing here.  I added a second y axis based on the second plot space and it displays 0 to 1 in line with the 0 to 100 y axis .. meaning that the 1 is in line with the 100.  I would have thought that the values for the second y axis which is around .14 would be displaying based on that axis, so. near 14 on the 0 to 100 plot space.  Even so, the value is still between 0 and 100.  Can you point me in the direction to understanding how the visible plot range works?

Comment: 0.14 is between 0 and 1 so it should be visible within either plot space. The `visibleRange` axis property only controls how the axis is labeled and drawn and has no effect on the plot. Normally, the axis line is drawn the full width or height of the plot area; this property lets you constrain the line so it only extends across part of the plot area.

Comment: So, what direction do I need to look in to get a line following a separate y axis from the rest?

Comment: Do you have a second y-axis tied to the second plot space? Does it show the expected range? Also, see my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks Eric,  That additional plot add line was commented out in my code.  I removed it from here.  I was switching between the two, if I used the simply add plot, the line was displayed. Plot to plotspace -- no line.

Comment: Also, my additional Y axis is displayed correctly, the line just doesn't plot

Comment: Is `self.plotSpace2` set correctly at the time you add the plot? Does the plot get its data from the datasource? If so, that says that its trying to draw, but the points aren't visible for some reason.